# Redirect loop when forcing SSL on Nginx server

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, tls, 301-redirect

Lately I have been trying to redirect to HTTPS using Nginx but I keep getting a redirect loop after I try to visit my site in a browser. Here is my full server block config file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm home.html contact.html projects.html;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name melone.co;
    return 301  https://$host$request_uri;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root /var/www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

After searching around I found out that `return 301  https://$host$request_uri;` would be the easiest way to do this.

So I implemented it into my config file, and ran `sudo service nginx restart`. I then went to my browser and I got a redirect loop. Once I removed that one line of code, it was gone. So what I think I'm really looking for is a more efficient way to redirect to SSL.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it stands, you're redirecting all traffic to `https`, which is good for `http` traffic, but for `https` traffic is quite pointless, and results in a redirection loop. What is happening right now is the following: `http` -> `https` -> `https` -> `https` -> `https` -> `https` ... and so on for quite a bit, up until the point where your browser tells you, "it's enough, we won't succeed".

What you want to achieve is redirecting `http` traffic to `https`, and process the `https` traffic (like you did before with the `http` traffic).

So, you've to split your config into two `server` directives: One for `http` (which should do the redirect), the other one for `https`, which will process the traffic.

Have a look at this example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name melone.co;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Add this `server` block to your config, remove the corresponding lines in your existing `server` block, and profit!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the issue. I need two server blocks. One listens on port 80 and redirects to 443.

I added this to the top of my conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
       server_name    melone.co;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```